# Javascript rendered multi-page table on ASP form: tear down DOM before moving to next page

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, selenium

Python + Selenium Chrome webdriver set up to work on some scraping; lxml library for the parsing. I need some help as I cannot get my head around this problem. I have a ASP webform, which essentially is the scaffolding around the query bottons/menus etc. The form is filled with a java script rendered table, over several pages. Page control is served as the bottom-most `<tr>` element of a table. Each frame has ten pages; the previous/next frame is rendered through a pointer to last/next page at the edges. The java script does a Postback with  Eventtarget and event argument fields.
Because the pagination moves sequentially, I am using an outermost loop to assert page numbers. For example, asserting page #11 on frame one (ten pages per frame) will take the view to the next frame and (Chrome) browser to page 11.
**Problem:** Suppose last page is *n* and now I assert page *n+1*. Selenium will not throw a 404 error. But since the last (n-th) page is still resident in the browser, the data scrape still dumps the n-th page. I cannot insert a stop condition as an explicit wait because the DOM is totally valid.
**Question:** How, if at all, can I tear down the last JS rendered table-view before calling the next page? Intuition: if I can scrap the last page, I can use expected conditions to insert a stop condition. I have read far and wide but could not find a work-around. Any help will be useful, and gratefully acknowledged.

Comment: I thought  of a workaround: to save some element of the first row of a page  _n_  and compare it with the same element on page _n+1_.The expected condition wait until item(n+1)!=item(n) would trip on the last page, leading to a timeout failure. Any ideas?